# How can I combine 1 cell with multiple other cells and drag down?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a file structure within google sheets. How can I take each cell in column K and append all cells in column L as a new cell in Column M? Ideally this would be draggable.

I tried to create the first set of values using K1 and appending column L then selecting them all and dragging down. Unfortunately the next name is column K jumps by the number of rows that I selected to drag.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this qualifies as complicated, but this should do it:

```
=FLATTEN(A1:A3&"\"&TRANSPOSE(B1:B4))
```

UPDATE:
This is in fact the demonstrated example on the [official FLATTEN() documentation page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761) from Google.
Thanks @marikamitsos for the heads up!

Comment: But of course Matt. This is the basic example at the official [FLATTEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761) page. You could probably add it to your answer.

Comment: @MattKing thank you, I had never used flatten(). I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround:**

While there may be a complicated formula to generate a list that concatenates every row with every other row, this can also be done in a custom function with a script. To do this, open **Tools -> Script Editor**, then use the code below:

```
function stackcolumn(val1, val2) {
  var result = [];
  for (i=0; i<val1.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<val2.length; j++) {
      var temp_result = val1[i][0]+"\\"+val2[j][0];
      result.push([temp_result]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Save the script, then you can now use the custom function `=STACKCOLUMN()` on the sheet like this:

[image]

**References:**

[Custom Functions | Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was unaware that I could reference script functions in cells like that. I learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula that will provide the desired results.

```
=Array_Constrain(ArrayFormula(Transpose(Split(Join("",REPT(A3:A&",",COUNTIF(B3:B,"<>"))),","))&"\"&Transpose(Split(Join(",",transpose(Split(Rept(JOIN(",",B3:B)&"|",Countif(A3:A,"<>")),"|"))),","))),Countif(A3:A,"<>")*CountIf(B3:B,"<>"),1)
```

This formula is based on the name fields being in `A3:A` and the folder names fields in `B3:B`